# ZF2 custom view helpers not registering / not found in AbstractPluginManager

Tags: php, zend-framework2

I have written a custom view helper, but I can't seem to figure out how to register it. Here is how what I tried:

```
'service_manager' => array(
...
),
'controllers' => array(
...
),
'controller_plugins' => array(
...
),

'view_manager' => array(
 ...
),
'view_helpers' => array(
    'invokables' => array(
        'slashesToDashes' => 'Applicaiton\View\Helper\SlashesToDashes',
),
```

Controllers, Controller Plugins, Services all these guys work fine. But the view helpers dont, although it should be the same as `controller_plugins`

Here is the entry from `autoload_classmap.php`

```
'Applicaiton\View\Helper\SlashesToDashes' => __DIR__ . '/src/Application/View/Helper/SlashesToDashes.php',
```

And the error that I get is:

```
Fatal error: Class 'Applicaiton\View\Helper\SlashesToDashes' not found in /var/www/my-project-name/vendor/zendframework/zendframework/library/Zend/ServiceManager/AbstractPluginManager.php on line 170
```

Any ideas why, ZF wont register the helper?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Notice the typo:

```
Fatal error: Class 'Applicaiton\View\Helper\SlashesToDashes'
                    Applicaiton\View\Helper\SlashesToDashes
                    Applicaiton
                           ti
```

Simply adjust your `invokables`

```
'view_helpers' => array(
    'invokables' => array(
        'slashesToDashes' => 'Application\View\Helper\SlashesToDashes',
    )
)
```

Another hint: there is a [`SeparatorToSeparator`](http://framework.zend.com/manual/2.1/en/modules/zend.filter.word.html#separatortoseparator) Filter present in the ZF2-Core. You can easily use this one to make a ViewHelper out of it ;)